# The assigned value is never used - Java

Tags: java

In my code I have the following lines:

```
 BinaryTreeNode temp = new BinaryTreeNode();
 temp = left;
 while(temp != null)
     temp = temp.left;

 temp.left = newNode;
```

My IDE now says that: "the assigned value is never used" on the first line. I am probably declaring something wrong.

Comment: Show us the entire method please..

Comment: Is left always null?

Comment: I am now a bit confused. What if I never want to read it? I just want to add a node.

Comment: you assign `temp = new BinaryTreeNode();` and then assign `temp = left` on the next string. so first assignment is unused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating a `BinaryTreeNode`, then throwing it away instantly (with `temp = left;`). The IDE is warning you about whether you really intend to do that.

You could use null instead, or assign `left` directly to `temp`.